# Keep track of items in array with timer

Tags: python, timer

I apologize I couldn't find a proper title, let me explain what I'm working on:

I have a Python IRC bot, and I want to be able to keep track of how long users have been idle in the channel, and allow them to earn things (I have it tied to Skype/Minecraft/my website) each x amount of hours they're idle in the channel.

I already have everything to keep track of each user and have them validated with the site and stuff, but I am not sure how I would keep track of the time they're idle.

I have it capture on join/leave/part messages. How can I get a timer set up when they join, and keep that timer running, along with other times for all of the users who are in that channel, and each hour they've been idle (not all at same time) do something then restart the timer over for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two general ways:

1. Create a separate timer for each user when he joins, do something when the timer fires and destroy it when the user leaves.
2. Have one timer set to fire, say, every second (or ten seconds) and iterate over all the users when it fires to see how long they have been idle.

A more precise answer would require deeper insight into your architecture, I’m afraid.

Comment: To add to this, the operative Python stdlib construct is `threading.Timer`, especially given that your IRC system is already probably multithreaded. For example, `timer = threading.Timer(SECONDS_PER_HOUR, check_all_idle)`

Comment: Let me also add then that going for [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/) is always the right thing to do when working with network and (especially) with asynchronous events.